# php reCAPTCHA not displaying

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am trying to add reCAPTCHA to my php/html site. But it does not display. I have downloaded the library and set up my site so I have the public and private keys. I have created a basic page to try and get this working but still no luck. This is my php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php
require_once('lib/recaptchalib.php');
?>
<title>Test odds and ends</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<?php
 $publickey = "~hidden~";
 echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The page displays completely blank. The html produced is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test odds and ends</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=~hidden~">
</script>
<noscript>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=~hidden~" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0">
</iframe><br/>
<textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
</noscript>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Firefox (29.0.1).

Comment: Do you mind sharing a link so I can try it in mine?

Comment: Looks like you have some plugins (noscript, ghostery, .....) blocking the recaptcha/script. It's not a PHP problem as the markup gets generated.